# Comparison of powers in the inequation of binary polynomials

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, cryptography, bit-strings

In "2.3 Analysis" of [Izu, Tetsuya et al. “Extending Bleichenbacher's Forgery Attack.” J. Inf. Process. 16 (2008): 122-129](https://ipsj.ixsq.nii.ac.jp/ej/?action=repository_action_common_download&item_id=9429&item_no=1&attribute_id=1&file_no=1) there is a move, which should be obvious, but I keep struggling with it. Could you help me with an explanation!

They use notion that *g* should be smaller than $2^{2α+β}$ and then move to consider powers using this higher value for LHS of inequality: $2α+β > 576+α+2β−log_2 3$. I understand that it comes from formula given few lines earlier in the article: $g(α, β) = a^2/3 × 2^{α+2β} − a^3/27 × 2^{3β}$, and by comparing the coefficients (and following logic they describe) I come to the conclusion that the first formula from "2.2 Outline of Bleichenbacher’s Attack" is used to construct the inequality (here's this formula: $a = 2^{288} − (T × 2^{160} + H(  \bar{m}))$).

But when we put *a* into the formula for *g(α, β)* we clearly are not getting something that could be expressed as a power of *2*. So how without this condition, without representing *g* as a power of *2* can we move to comparison of powers leaving out other members of polynomial?

PS It's my first question in Math section, please hint me if there's anything wrong in it.